# Why WebUtility.HtmlDecode is not decode complete in my text in c#?

Tags: c#

Here is my text:

```
"&lt;p&gt;求助,我现在遇到这样一个问题:&lt;/p&gt;"
"&lt;p&gt;就是在rdlc报表中需要输出一些带下标的字符串,例如:&lt;/p&gt;"
"&lt;p&gt;一&lt;sub&gt;班&lt;/sub&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
"&lt;p&gt;我在数据库中保存了 :一&amp;lt;sub&amp;gt;班&amp;lt;/sub&amp;gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
"&lt;p&gt;但在rdlc报表中显示出来就是:一&amp;lt;sub&amp;gt;班&amp;lt;/sub&amp;gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
" &lt;p&gt;怎样才能显示&quot;一&lt;sub&gt;班&lt;/sub&gt;&quot;这个结果啊.&lt;/p&gt;";
```

When I use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text)`, I get the following:

```
" <p>求助,我现在遇到这样一个问题:</p>
  <p>就是在rdlc报表中需要输出一些带下标的字符串,例如:</p>
  <p>一<sub>班</sub></p>
  <p>我在数据库中保存了 :一&lt;sub&gt;班&lt;/sub&gt;</p>
  <p>但在rdlc报表中显示出来就是:一&lt;sub&gt;班&lt;/sub&gt;</p>
  <p>怎样才能显示\"一<sub>班</sub>\"这个结果啊.</p>"
```

The decode is incomplete and not full, It will be right when I execute the HtmlDecode again, Why should I decode twice?

Comment: As I can see, the `&`s are coded too and they must be decoded to completely decode certain characters. Which is weird because there are some `&`s already in the first text...

Comment: @Shinratensei right, I also confused at the text, but it came from user input.

Comment: Sometimes, with some Syndication (RSS) feeds, you have to decode the content 3/4 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. `&amp;` is `&` after HtmlEncode. So it will be decode twice.